# Michael Hartl - Chapter 6 - User class becomes nil and throws undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, rspec-rails, rspec2

I'm learning Ruby on rails using http://railstutorial.org/ . While going through chapter 6 in his book. I came across my user fields becoming nil. Which in turn causes the authenticate method to fail.

FYI I have used rails 5 and ruby 2.6 all lastest Gems unlike the one mentioned in the tutorial.

This is Rspec results after running the tests

```
$bundle exec rspec spec/
including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!

Randomized with seed 55216
............F..........FFF..F...

Failures:

  1) User should be valid
     Failure/Error: it { should be_valid }
       expected #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Password can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:27:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User return value of authenticate method with valid password should When you call a matcher in an example without a String, like this:

specify { expect(object).to matcher }

or this:

it { is_expected.to matcher }

RSpec expects the matcher to have a #description method. You should either
add a String to the example this matcher is being used in, or give it a
description method. Then you won't have to suffer this lengthy warning again.

     Failure/Error: it { should == found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:64:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) User return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
     Failure/Error: let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:68:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:71:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  4) User return value of authenticate method with invalid password should not When you call a matcher in an example without a String, like this:

specify { expect(object).to matcher }

or this:

it { is_expected.to matcher }

RSpec expects the matcher to have a #description method. You should either
add a String to the example this matcher is being used in, or give it a
description method. Then you won't have to suffer this lengthy warning again.

     Failure/Error: let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:68:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:70:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  5) User when email format is valid should be valid
     Failure/Error: @user.should be_valid
       expected #<User id: nil, name: nil, email: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, password_digest: nil> to be valid, but got errors: Password can't be blank
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:96:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:94:in `each'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:94:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Deprecation Warnings:

Using `should` from rspec-expectations' old `:should` syntax without explicitly enabling the syntax is deprecated. Use the new `:expect` syntax or explicitly enable `:should` with `config.expect_with(:rspec) { |c| c.syntax = :should }` instead. Called from /home/user/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/models/user_spec.rb:96:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'.


If you need more of the backtrace for any of these deprecations to
identify where to make the necessary changes, you can configure
`config.raise_errors_for_deprecations!`, and it will turn the
deprecation warnings into errors, giving you the full backtrace.

1 deprecation warning total

Finished in 0.49086 seconds (files took 0.54848 seconds to load)
32 examples, 5 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:27 # User should be valid
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:64 # User return value of authenticate method with valid password should When you call a matcher in an example without a String, like this:

specify { expect(object).to matcher }

or this:

it { is_expected.to matcher }

RSpec expects the matcher to have a #description method. You should either
add a String to the example this matcher is being used in, or give it a
description method. Then you won't have to suffer this lengthy warning again.

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:71 # User return value of authenticate method with invalid password 
rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:70 # User return value of authenticate method with invalid password should not When you call a matcher in an example without a String, like this:

specify { expect(object).to matcher }

or this:

it { is_expected.to matcher }

RSpec expects the matcher to have a #description method. You should either
add a String to the example this matcher is being used in, or give it a
description method. Then you won't have to suffer this lengthy warning again.

rspec ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:92 # User when email format is valid should be valid

Randomized with seed 55216
```

**Project**

[sample_app/tree/modelling_user](https://github.com/Kaushik-Vijayakumar/sample_app/tree/modelling_user)

**Files**

[spec/models/user_spec.rb](https://github.com/Kaushik-Vijayakumar/sample_app/blob/modelling_user/spec/models/user_spec.rb)

[app/models/user.rb](https://github.com/Kaushik-Vijayakumar/sample_app/blob/modelling_user/app/models/user.rb)

[Gemfile](https://github.com/Kaushik-Vijayakumar/sample_app/blob/modelling_user/Gemfile)

Comment: "User class becomes nil" - no. The __class__ is fine. It's just your `found_user` is set to nil instead of a User object. Must be you deviated from the tutorial somewhere. Take a few steps back and retry.

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev Couldn't acutally find out what went wrong. But tried changing  
`let(:found_user) { User.find_by_email(@user.email) }` 
to 
`found_user = User.find_by_email(@user.email)` 
and the error was
 `Failure/Error: puts @user.email

NoMethodError:
  undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: Interesting. At a glance, there's nothing in that spec file that could nil the `@user`... Some debugging is needed.

Comment: Hint: your user is not being saved to the DB. Some kind of error. Can you figure this out? (you _did_ deviate from tutorial, after all).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev when i tried to add row using new method it created a row with all nil values but when I used the create method it created the row properly. But for testing I don't need to access the DB right?. 
PS: Somehow my tests passed once I restarted my system. Now I'm using new method and its working fine. Any idea what would have possibly gone wrong.

Comment: No, no idea. If `new` didn't work, `create` shouldn't work either. Unless you changed something in the meanwhile. I know what the problem _was_, but you must have fixed it, knowingly or not.